# Java move a drawn image by clicking some where on the applet?

Tags: java

how can i move a image that is drawn using `g.drawImage` when you click some where on the applet it will slide to that position?

Comment: How about giving us a piece of your code? Do you want to move the image instantly, slide id smoothly or provide variation in motion speed? You should probably place a counter variable in your class and refer to it in the paint method. You might also need a timer and a separate thread to move it slowly after the click is performed. Do you have any MouseEvents in your code as it is now?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) on the applet. Basically, you can define your own in the applet by `implements MouseListener`. Then, when you grab the mouse location on a click (override `public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me)`), you can redraw the image. [This is a good example of a MouseListener on an Applet](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/MouseClickExample.html)